# Does it make sense to have both 'apt' and 'apt-get' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

If we have [apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-get), we might as well have [apt-cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-cache) and [apt-cdrom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-cdrom). Maybe we can make these symlinks to [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt)?

Answer (score 4):

I made the [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) ← [apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-get) synonym; I'll wait to merge them in case somebody raises an issue here

Answer (score 3):

That's been [discussed briefly on Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/787/bad-synonym-for-apt).

I tend to err towards ultra-specific tags. Given the low volume, I'm ok with making [apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-get) a synonym of [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) (as well as `apt-cache` and `apt-cdrom` if they pop up). On the other hand, I favor keeping [aptitude](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aptitude) separate, as well as other tools that are built around apt (`apt-file`, `synaptic`, etc) if they pop up.